# How would i send text from an edit textbox to another app?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi im trying to develop and app which requires sending of text from one edit text box to another app such as Kik, i have already made the Share menu i just need to make it send the text from my edit text box

heres my share menu code (XML):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:title="Share"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:actionProviderClass= "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

</menu>
```

And heres my java:

```
package com.example.Encryptor_Kik;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 12/12/13
 * Time: 3:15 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class Decryptor extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.decryption);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);

    ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and at the time of creating it your `EditText` is empty so the `text` is empty. You need to add a listener for change of text. Here is full code-

```
public class Decryptor extends Activity {
EditText e;
private ShareActionProvider mShare;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.decryption);
    e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.YourID);
    e.addTextChangedListener(commonTextWatcher);


     TextWatcher commonTextWatcher
    = new TextWatcher(){

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   String text=e.getText.toString();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    if (mShare != null) {
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent); 
    } 
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
    String text=e.getText.toString();
    mShare = (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

Comment: i did as you said there are no errors but it doesn't 'share' the text from it

Comment: @LochlanKennedy Show the code. How have you implemented what I said??